# How to reduce chassis fan speed with software?

Tags: motherboard, fan, speedfan

I have replaced an old broken motherboard in a Dell Inspiron (slimline chassis) with a Asus P5KLM-AM motherboard. Now the chassis fan runs at full speed (3750 RPM) at all times, which is very loud.

How can I reduce fan speeds, (and noise)? I tried SpeedFan which was not able to control the fan (it says it goes down to 0%, but the fan still runs).

I would love a software solution, that runs at bootup silently (SpeedFan won't run automatically because it requires administrator privileges), which could reduce the fan speed to a preset level. Does that exist?

Answer (score 1):

That board isn't listed by Asus.  I'm guessing it's an Asus model made specifically for OEM's like Dell and HP.

A close, retail board to it (listed by Asus) is the P5KPL-AM, which supports [Asus' Q-Fan technology](http://www.asus.com/999/html/events/mb/qfan.htm).

> ASUS Q-Fan Smart Cooling System Enables Quieter and More Efficient Fan Operation

If the board does support it, there will probably also be an option to toggle it on and off in the BIOS.

[image]

But this is hard to guess, as the board may not use a standard BIOS (it may use one customized by Dell or alike).

Still probably worth a try, assuming the chassis fans are attached to the motherboard and not directly to the power supply.

Comment: The board does have the Q-Fan option in BIOS, but enabling it seems to make no difference.

Comment: You may need to install a utility from Asus (like PC-Probe), depending on your version of Windows, and the fact that it seems you have a non-retail board, you may have to dig around a little to get the right version.

Comment: The link is broken.